# VirtualBox guest Win10 @ Linux host hangs big time at startup, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, troubleshooting

I have a VirtualBox VM running Windows 10 on a Linux host. It used to work just fine, but this day when I started it it hangs big time.

The VM’s window is just a black square, and also the host hangs up. 
I can’t even switch to another console
with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

**How can I start troubleshooting this?** (I don't have any snapshots to go back to.)

---

**UPDATE:** After:

Removed all Virtualbox packages:

```
apt auto-remove 'virtualbox*'
```

Reinstalled latest version (first add repositiory of needed (see virtualbox.org):

```
apt install virtualbox-5.2
```

It works again as of 2018-02-20 on `4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu`.

Comment: You didn't perchance install any updates?

Comment: Have you tried accessing with a live USB without any updates? I'm having the same problem on Linux Mint 18.3 with the latest version of the kernel. I have a strong suspicion those meltdown/spectre patches have killed linux's ability to run any type of VM.  @gerard-h-pile do you agree?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille + James Draper !! That's right. I did install updates. That's a very probable reason. I will check that out and post back in a couple of days.

Comment: @JamesDraper Was indeed the reason I asked.  I'm afraid there's an interesting year ahead.

Comment: It was indeed the latest kernel update that caused the problem. Booted with the previous kernel today, and the VM runs 很好！ (`uname -a` outputs `4.10.0-42-generic`) So thankful for you help all, this must cause a lot of trouble for a lot of people at present. God bless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be due to a recent kernel update. You can try booting an older kernel.

You can create a GRUB menu entry for an older kernel (anything less than 4.13) by doing the following:

1) Find out which kernels you have installed by running this in the terminal:

```
$ls /boot/vmlinuz*
```

2) Then find the disk UUID that is you system root (not the swap):

```
$ll /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

3) Then then in a text file substitute those values into the menu entry below:

```
menuentry "Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit, with Linux 4.10.0-38-generic" {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-X.X.X-XX-generic root=UUID=XXXX-YYYY ro  quiet splash
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-X.X.X-XX-generic
}
```

4) Open the custom GRUB menu for editing:

```
$sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

5) Copy and paste your modified menu entry into 40_custom save. Then run:

```
$sudo update-grub
```

You could even set that to the grub default if you wanted too.

I would use this kernel with caution as time goes on for obvious reasons. Hopefully a patch for the patch will come soon but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel update in last days is a reason. Try to boot to older kernel. I think some meltdown patch or something similar is a source of this problem.

### How to boot to an older kernel

1. Reboot and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when computer starts. Grub-menu opens.
2. Choose "Advanced ..."
3. Choose your preferred old kernel to boot from it.